# Why is my startActivityForResult() returning null when converting ArrayList<String> to String[]?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

The following code is throwing a `NullPointerException` because the `ArrayList` isn't being converted to an Array correctly. The array is supposed to be passed to another activity. This works because I can pass a regular `String[]` but when I  try to convert an `ArrayList` to Array I get the error. What's the right way to convert `ArrayList` to Array?

```
String[] tmpHtml = new String[(siteElements.size())];
tmpHtml = (String[]) siteElements.toArray();
Intent returnResult = new Intent();
returnResult.putExtra("elements", tmpHtml);
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnResult);
finish();
```

Comment: I would have expected a ClassCastException. `toArray` with no argument returns an `Object[]`.

Comment: Ahh yes it was a ClassCastException. Getting tired :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you covert the ArrayList to String array was wrong.
The correct way is:

```
tmpHtml = siteElements.toArray(tmpHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changwei Yao's answer will work, but why not

```
// put to intent
returnResult.putStringArrayListExtra("elements", siteElements);
// Get from intent
returnResult.getStringArrayListExtra("elements");
```